# LDAP authentication in ATK4

Tags: php, ldap, atk4

Does ATK4 supports LDAP authentication? I would like to query LDAP and automatically add the account to the atk4 application while the user authenticates for the first time. Subsequent authentications requests should check the passwords from the LDAP itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Agile Toolkit is the User Interface framework and it focuses on visualizing data and improving interaction between user and the server.

The MySQL is integrated for data storage, however you can integrate a [built-in LDAP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ldap.php) functionality with the UI by creating a Controller.

You can extend BasicAuth class by looking at DBAuth as example and implementing the LDAP connectivity for user authentication and user mirroring into regular Models.

The resulting class might be quite useful for others, so it would be nice if you share it.

Comment: @romaninsh I have developed LdapAuth, how can I contribute it to atk4 or atk4-addons ?

Comment: @luiggitama, Create a github repository and also add it to packagist. Here is the documentation page but I'm still working on it: http://book.agiletoolkit.org/addons.html

Comment: @romaninsh My LdapAuth is based on Agile Toolkit 4.2.4. Should I wait for version 4.3 to be released?